# Vertically aligning only 2 items on a full-screen page

Tags: css, alignment

I have more than 2 image items placed in various positions against a full screen background image (container). I only need the two image items in the center to align horizontally down the middle of the page/screen. This also needs to be responsive ie. when the browser window is contracted horizontally I want the two items to move towards the middle in tandem with each other. With the code I am trying, one  of the two items is not lining up with the other, and is in fact moving a little left of center when the browser screen is contracted to mimic portrait mode. What is the issue? I am positioning absolutely and using `margin: auto` on both. Here is **[the code](https://jsfiddle.net/qz7531bu/)**. Would appreciate any light.

PS, for some reason the arrow is moving up and down in the jfiddle, while retaining its horizontal alignment; this is not happening in my case; in my case the arrow is only retaining its vertical position (as  i want it), but moving off centre when i contract the browser width (which is not what i want; i need it to keep it horizontal position at the center as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the two divs horizontally and vertically (i.e. the dead center of the screen!) you can use the following CSS...

```
#div1,
#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  }
```

If you want the images to respond to the screens width then adding a maximum width on the images would fix that.

```
img {max-width: 100%;}
```

Comment: yes - this kind of lead me to the problem - which is that I was adjust the logo's dimensions with a media query, but i wasnt doing the same with the arrow... thnx.

Comment: Give the arrow a transparent background that is the same width as the larger image. This way they will scale at the same dimentions

Comment: Sure - thanks - in fact in the actual version it is transparent, but am doing the dimension tweeks.